# How close a file opened by java.awt.Desktop

Tags: java, file, awt

How to close an opened excel file?

Open excel code is:

```
File file = new File("e:\\aaa.xlsx");
Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
desktop.open(file);
```

What would be the close code?

just using java open and close Windows application like use mouse.

Comment: As an aside `new File("e;\\aaa.xlsx");` should probably be `new File("e:\\aaa.xlsx");`

Comment: @JoopEggen  Since that *is* the answer, why not upgrade it to an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Forget it. Open here means that the registered application, Excel, takes over and opens a Window. After that you have no control, but watching. Excel will close.

File is a class that represents a file system path. Itself it has no state of associated reader/writer. Java 7 now parallel introduces a more evolved class Path. Besides (obviously) the path on the file system, it also stores what file system. With Path one can have more than one FileSystem, like a ZipFileSystem. That allows you to copy and rename files in a zip.

*That was just an elaboration.*

Comment: thank you ! any other solution for open and close excel file?

Comment: Do you mean reading/writing an Excel file in java, or starting/quitting the Excel application? I believe, an Excel sheet might even be used as a database with ODBC/JDBC [link](http://www.ehow.com/how_4810548_use-jdbc-connect-ms-excel.html). Though much one sees Apache POI and such.

Comment: start and close excel,like in Windows.thank you . (sorry , my english is very bad)

Comment: Maybe with its own [process](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-run-another-application-from-java.html).